# GPUImageVideoCamera save video on ios 7

Tags: gpuimage

I'm trying to achieve the square video recording like 300*300 so I choose GPUImage but its not working on IOS 7 and giving errors like `[UIView nextAvailableTextureIndex]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` the error starts when we build the even the sample code
when trying to save the `GPUImageVideoCamera`
some times its stucks at `[movieWriter startRecording];` 
is the GPUImage compatible with ios 7 or we have made some changes ?

here is the code

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad
        {
            [super viewDidLoad];

            videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];


            videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
            videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorFrontFacingCamera = NO;
            videoCamera.horizontallyMirrorRearFacingCamera = NO;

            filter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];

        initWithRotation:kGPUImageRotateRightFlipVertical];

            [videoCamera addTarget:filter];
            GPUImageView *filterView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
            [filter addTarget:filterView];
       sharing

            NSString *pathToMovie = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Movie.m4v"];
            unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]); // If a file already exists, AVAssetWriter won't let you record new frames, so delete the old movie
            NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];
            movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(480.0, 640.0)];

            [filter addTarget:movieWriter];

        }



- (IBAction)stopRecording:(id)sender {

    [filter removeTarget:movieWriter];
    videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = nil;
    [movieWriter finishRecording];

}

- (IBAction)startRecording:(id)sender {

    videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
    [movieWriter startRecording];
    [videoCamera startCameraCapture];

}
```

Comment: GPUImageVideoCamera and GPUImageMovieWriter work just great under iOS7. Show some code on how you're setting up the GPUImage filter chain.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you modified the .xib or storyboard and didn't set the class of the view that is showing the camera preview to `GPUImageView`.

[image: see image]

Comment: that was the previous one now check my updated code and see the new errors 


"_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageCropFilter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in recordViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageMovieWriter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in recordViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageVideoCamera", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in recordViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPUImageView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in recordViewController.o

Comment: This is another error, so it should post another question. The linker is not seeing the GPUImage library. Check that GPUImage is listed under the Target Dependencies in your project target. For further problems check the official documentation here https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#adding-the-framework-to-your-ios-project