# SIGABRT error: App crashes if running forceProcessingAtSize: (GPUImage Framework)

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage, sigabrt

My app crashes in the debug mode if I run this line of code:

```
[brightnessFilter forceProcessingAtSize:imgView2.sizeInPixels];
```

This is the whole code:

```
UIImage *inputImage = imgView.image;

sourcePicture = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage smoothlyScaleOutput:YES];
brightnessFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
//    sepiaFilter = [[GPUImageSobelEdgeDetectionFilter alloc] init];

GPUImageView *imgView2 = (GPUImageView *)self.view;
[brightnessFilter forceProcessingAtSize:imgView2.sizeInPixels];

[sourcePicture addTarget:brightnessFilter];
[brightnessFilter addTarget:imgView2];

[sourcePicture processImage];
```

This is the log:

```
2014-05-13 16:04:46.671 Picxxr[5341:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView sizeInPixels]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109fbed60'
```

My imgView:

```
imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 320)];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

Comment: You probably didn't change the class of your view to GPUImageView in the .xib or storyboard. Check my previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041977/gpuimagevideocamera-save-video-on-ios-7/22042692#22042692

Comment: How can I change the class via the .m file (via code) I created my ImageView with code and not the storyboard. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Now I have an UIImageView inside my storyboard. But if I chose my UIImageView and will change the class, I can only chose UIImageView and not GPUImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you shared is probably inside the implementation file of one of your `UIViewController`'s which I'm sure has an associated .xib or lies somewhere inside a storyboard.

Now take that `UIViewController`, select the root view (the white background of the view controller) and change its class from `UIView` to `GPUImageView` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041977/gpuimagevideocamera-save-video-on-ios-7/22042692#22042692).

Comment: I haven't an image View in storyboard. I created my imgView in the .m file (code in the question).

Comment: In the storyboard you have an UIView change that one. The other answer I linked may have mislead you. It just shows where to change the class in the storyboard.

Comment: Ohh no! I thought I have to chage it in the image View :) My incorrect. Sorry and thanks for your answer!

Comment: But it's still crashing.

Comment: Yes. The same crash log.

Comment: Ok. Now I change the class from UIView to GPUImageView. But if I'll run my app it crashes. Xcode says: `2014-05-27 21:25:36.181 CameraApp[6112:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView sizeInPixels]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109d19930'` and here `-[UIView ` it says that it is an UIView. But why? I changed it to GPUImageView.

Comment: You may want to post your project to Github, it will be easier to check what is going wrong here. Anyhow debugger doesn't lie, you're sending a `sizeInPixels` to a `UIView`. You may have changed the class to the wrong instance or your outlets aren't setup properly.

Comment: I checked all the outputs. And it's still not working. This the link, where you can download the app project: dropbox.com/s/jptaw4ycham3io8/CameraApp.zip

Comment: Why don't you write me back? Did I something wrong? I've a bad conscience.

Comment: Frankly this is going far from the original question. Anyhow did you notice the error that comes out in the console right at the beginning when running your project?? *Unknown class GPUImageView in Interface Builder file*. Please take a better look to https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#adding-the-framework-to-your-ios-project.